# Monitor control property

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a  `uiviewcontroller`, which contains custom control;  I need to monitor a property in it such that

if it becomes true I hide the back button in navigation bar, else allow it.

is it applicable in iOS and objective c; if yes how to implement   that

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Assuming your object has a property called "boolValue":

```
[obj addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"boolValue" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];



- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
   BOOL value=[object boolValue];
   if (value)
   {
     // hide back button
   }
   else
   {
     // show back button
   }
}
```

Comment: Remember to remove observer when it's not needed anymore (`viewDidUnload`?) or else you'll [leak observation info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488504/observation-info-was-leaked). God kills a kitten everytime you do this.